# Calling a Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods

I figured out the problem to the assignment below. Just out of curiosity, when I'm calling the "Method? why is that I need the two quotation? When I removed it on tom, I get an error message saying undefined local variable or method. Please help me understand this concept!

```
# 2.
# Write a method that reverses
# a string ONLY if it's shorter than
# 4 letters. 


def reverse_test(practice)
    if practice.length<4
        practice=practice.reverse
    else puts practice 
    end
end

reverse_test("tom")
```

Comment: Some clarification, please: _"problem to the assignment below"_ – the only assignment in your code is `practice=practice.reverse`. _"I need the two quotation"_ – what does "two quotation" mean? _"When I removed it on tom, I get an error message"_ – could you show that code including the full error message?

Comment: `tom` is a name of something. You don't have anything in your program named `tom`, hence you get said error. `"tom"` on the other hand is a string, constructed with the characters `t`, `o` and `m`.

Comment: Nathan, check out the "Programming Ruby" book (http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) especially the "Classes, Objects, and Variables" chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly re-writing your code with better indentation and spacing:

```
def reverse_test(practice)
  if practice.length < 4
    practice.reverse
  else
    practice 
  end
end
```

Your error message says `undefined local variable or method`, which in this case means you're trying pass a variable that doesn't exist. So define your variable first then you can pass it into the method like so:

```
tom_variable = "tom"
puts reverse_test(tom_variable)
#=> mot
```

#### Notes

Any printing (i.e. using `puts`) should be done when calling the method and not within the method definition itself; There's no need to redefine `practice` in your `if-branch`, you're only interested in the return value; in your `else-branch`, put the return value on the next line.

#### practice

The parameter `practice` you've defined must be an object that responds to both the `length` and `reverse` methods. A String-object is such an object.

Answer (score 0):

The method is expecting a string as a input parameter. So when you are invoking it, you pass string "tom" to it so it is double-quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand the difference between variables and strings.

```
def length(string)
  print string.length
end

# this is assignment
string_variable = "string_literal"

# this is an equality check, it returns true
string_variable == "string_literal"

length(string_variable)
length("string literal")
```